# apache commons FileUtils.copyFile error Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested

Tags: java, tomcat

A program using FileUtils.copyFile() using to copy files which is failed to copy 500MB file after that it was failing for small sized files. Like it use to copy 30MB files now it was not case threshold of max size dropped to <10MB. 
This program was running under tomcat restarted server tomcat doesn't fix. But restarted machine started working again anyone know what is java file copy relates to System resources.

Runnning tomcat 7 , jdk 7 on window 2003 server.

Comment: Since you use JDK 7+, drop File and use JSR 203 instead; Java has `Files.copy()` now

Comment: commons also using nio package to copy files how does it will effect

Comment: No, FileUtils doesn't use Path.

Comment: what special with Path class in java 7

Comment: It avoids all the pitfalls of `File`, for one; and you can do [so much more with it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTNuCxPJX5g).

Answer (score 0):

**credits to FGE**

> used Java 7+  JSR 203 specs `Files.copy()` class to fix this issue it
>   worked like a champ